# How to get ID from Parent object when field value matches

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, map

I have a requirement to update Account_Transfer__c(Child) object with District Name(Parent) when a field value matches on child record.

below is the logic that I've achieved so far

```
   insert accTransferPolicy; //inserting Account Transfer Policy record (grand child)
    Map<string, District__c> mapATwithDistrict = new Map<string, District__c>();
    for (District__c dst : [
            SELECT id, Name
            FROM District__c
            WHERE Status__c = 'OPEN' ]) {
            mapATwithDistrict.put(dst.Name, dst);
        }
    for (Account_Transfer_Policy__c c : accTransferPolicy) {
        if (c.Account_Transfer__c != null) {
            if (mapATwithDistrict.containsKey(c.Account_Transfer__r.District_From__c)) {
                    c.Account_Transfer__r.Transfer_From__c = mapATwithDistrict.get(Name).Id;
                }
        }            
        update c;
    }
```

From the above code, the hierarchy is as:

> Account_Transfer_Policy (grand child) --> Account_Transfer__c (Child) --> District__c (Parent)

Now, from the above code, i'm getting the error as

> Variable does not exist: Name

can anyone please let me know on how to update Transfer_From__c field with matching district Name Id
when District name on District__c record and District_From__c on Account Transfer record matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SK_112,

Since you're assigning the District's Name as the key for *mapATwithDistrict* Map, you'll need to use the name to retrieve the Id.

**Change From:**

```
if (mapATwithDistrict.containsKey(c.Account_Transfer__r.District_From__c)) {
                c.Account_Transfer__r.Transfer_From__c = mapATwithDistrict.get(<How to get matching district id>).Id;
            }
```

**Change To:**

```
if (mapATwithDistrict.containsKey(c.Account_Transfer__r.**District__r.Name**)) {
                c.Account_Transfer__r.Transfer_From__c = mapATwithDistrict.get(c.Account_Transfer__r.**District__r.Name**).Id;
            }
```

Comment: if I use c.Account_Transfer__r.**District__r.Name**, I will be getting the District name only when Account Transfer record has District record. Here, I dont have it and I want Account Transfer to update with District name so that both the records will be related.

Comment: Also, When I use your suggested code, the Account_Transfer__c record didnt updated with District__c name. Please suggest

Comment: SK_12, I see now.  Is it safe to assume the "District_From__c" values will be an EXACT match to the District's Name.  For instance, the value of "District_From__c" will be "Northeast", and there will be a District Record with a Name of "Northeast". If that's true, simply use "c.Account_Transfer__r.Transfer_From__c = mapATwithDistrict.get(c.Account_Transfer__r.District_From__c).Id".  If they are not an EXACT match, you'll need to use a leverage a unique key to perform the matching

Comment: @SFJeci, I am getting the error as "Variable does not exists: District_From__c"

Comment: Can you share the entire class/trigger?

Comment: only this part is related to this implementation.

Comment: Based on the error and not having access to the entire implementation, it seems that "Account_Transfer__r.District_From__c" field is not being populated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110133/discussion-between-sk-112-and-sf-jedi).